# Parsing datetime in textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, date

I have datetime in one simple textbox. The format of the textbox's value can be anything like DD/MM/YYYY or MM/DD/YYYY. I want to parse this using DateTime.Parse(string). Currently for some dates it works and for others it throws Exception. How do I handle this? How do I make sure that no matter what format is provided it always parses correct (as long as it is valid date)?

Thanks in advance :)

**EDIT**

As there is no fix answer to it I modify my question to ask how do I convert it to MM/DD/YYYY?  What should I provide in IFormatProvider of DateTime.Parse?

Comment: Did you check with `.TryParse` ?

Comment: No I haven't checked. Should I check?

Comment: if you can put in DD/MM/YYYY and MM/DD/YYYY how do you know Whether 06/12/2011 resolves to June 12th or December 6th?

Comment: I believe it uses the format of the current Culture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DateTime needs to know how to parse the date otherwise it won't know whether 05/07/2011 is the 5th July or the 7th May. Wouldn't it be better to use a calendar control to remove this ambiguity?

Comment: It definitely would be. However I am given the code developed by someone else and he has developed using textbox and jquery calendar control.

Comment: This is not a solution because not SOLVE the PARSE problem

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a fixed format.  You may even allow your users to select the format they want to use.  But you absolutely need to know the format.  Then you could use `DateTime.TryParseExact`.  For instance, what would 01/03/2011 mean?  It could be mm/dd/yyyy *or* dd/mm/yyyy.  You really need to be explicit about this.

Answer (score 1):

I came here to figure out if I can find a better solution than mine.
I already saw some of this solution propose here in other post and google. What IMHO works better is follow:

```
    DateTime date;
    bool isDate = (DateTime.TryParseExact(txtbxDATETIME.Value, 
                                               "yyyy'/'MM'/'dd",
                                                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                                DateTimeStyles.None,
                                                out date));
   //possible use:
   DateTime someDATEorVAr =  (isDate) ? date : DateTime.Now;
```

Hope somebody find this useful

Answer (score 0):

That parsing problem can be solved by using the TryParse(String, IFormatProvider, DateTimeStyles, DateTime) variant so that culture info (most commonly I use CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) can be passed to it and thus removing the ambiguity.

[DateTime.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx)

Vijay